# How to set php mysql from javascript var or input type text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

How to set php mysql from javascript var or input type text ?

This is my php mysql code:

```
<?PHP
$count = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($count <= 36))
{
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    $count++;
}
?>
```

And this is my javascript for check clientwidth and set value into input type text

```
<input type="text" id="width"/>
<script>
var width=window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth
document.getElementById("width").value = width;
</script>
```

I want to do like this

if var javascript `width > 1599` i want to use this code php my sql

```
<?PHP
$count = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($count <= 40))
{
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    $count++;
}
?>
```

else `width <= 1599`

```
<?PHP
$count = 1;
$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ORDER BY RAND()";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while( ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($count <= 36))
{
    $uid = $row['uid'];
    $count++;
}
?>
```

How can i do that?

thank you

Comment: On the surface, this looks like a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php but I think there are some deeper lessons that could be learned by the OP. @mongmongseesee, why do you want to do this?

Comment: u may take use of cookies

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a **client-side** script language execute on client web browser but PHP is a **server-side** script language execute on server.

Therefore, to archive triggering server-side script by client side script, you might need to create a server-side endpoint and trigger the endpoint with AJAX.

You can find an example of PHP AJAX and MYSQL from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).